# How to remove the first fragment if I reached sixth fragment using backstack?

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have only One fragment and I am creating instances of it every time I clicked the constraintLayout. When I reached the sixth instance of that same fragment, how can I remove the first fragment instance? Basically, my process is like an array that has a maximum element of 5, and if the sixth element comes in I want to remove the first element. I used this code below:

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_fragment, container, false);
        TextView message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
        ConstraintLayout product = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product);

        Bundle data = getArguments();
        if (data != null) {
            data_1 = Integer.parseInt(data.getString("data_1"));
            message.setText("" + data_1);
        }

        product.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (data_1 == 5){
                    if (getFragmentManager() != null) {
                        getFragmentManager().popBackStack("1", 0); //But this process will move you back to first fragment so this is incorrect.
                    }
                }

                data_1++;
                Fragment fragment = new ProductFragment();
                Bundle data = new Bundle();
                data.putString("data_1", String.valueOf(data_1));
                fragment.setArguments(data);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(data_1));
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }
```

I used `popBackStack()` because I thought that it was like the `pop()` method in array. Is there a way to do these?

Answer (score 0):

The fragment back stack is a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)); the only Fragment you can operate on is the topmost fragment. That means there's no way to reach down into the stack and remove the bottommost fragment without also removing all fragments above it on the stack.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve what I want to happen?